# Prove that $f'(x_0)=c$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

> Let $f:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $x_0 \in (a,b)$. $f$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$. Also, Let $l(x)= cx+d$, "passes" at $(x_0, f(x_0))$.
>   Prove that if $\forall x \in (a,b):f(x) \ge l(x)$ then $f'(x_0)=c$.

It looked suitable using the derivative definition here:

$$f'(x) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f({x_0} + h) - f({x_0})}}{h} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f({x_0} + h) - c{x_0} - d}}{h}$$

But how to continue from here? (If that's the desirable way)

EDIT:

---

Maybe defining $g(x)=f(x)-l(x)$ is the right way to the conclusion?

The derivative is: $g'(x) = f'(x)-l'(x) = f'(x)-c$.
Comparing the derivative to $0$ we get:
$f'(x)-c = 0$. Therefore, $f'(x)=c$.

So we know that when $g'(x)=0$, then $f'(x)=c$, but what can we learn from it?

Comment: Indeed. It's a type. thanks

Comment: Oh, now that's waaaaaay another thing after the editing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: By the Taylor expansion (or [linear approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_approximation)) of $f$ around $x_0$ you have that $$f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+R_2=f'(x_0)x+e$$ where $e=f(x_0)-f'(x_0)x_0+R_2$ (to simplify notation. In fact $e$ as defined depends on x, but for values of x close to $x_0$ it can be arbitrarily small). Now if assume $f'(x_0)\neq c$ we will get that $f(x)<l(x)$ for either $x<x_0$ or $x>x_0$ which is a contradiction to $f(x)\ge l(x)$ for all $x\in (a,b)$.

Comment: How can you tell that $e$ can be arbitrary small around $x_0$?

Comment: I read it in the link that I posted to you (in wikipedia, about linear approximation).

Comment: Now that I see it again, your idea leads to shorter proof (if I am not mistaken, see the other answer that I posted). Besides, for the linear approximation that I suggested you need that $f$ is twice differentiable which is not stated in your exercise.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea of defining $g(x)$ is correct. Since $g(x)\ge 0$ by the property $f(x)\ge l(x)$ you have that the minimum of $g$ is at $x_0$ since $$g(x_0)=f(x_0)-l(x_0)=0$$ So, since there is the minimum you have that $g'(x_0)=0$ (by the first derivative criterion for a minimum of a differentiable function). But this means that $$0=g'(x_0)=f'(x_0)-l'(x_0)=f'(x_0)-c$$ which implies that $f'(x_0)=c$.